# PostgreSQL how to set a Primary Key column with timestamp to automatically be filled

Tags: timestamp, postgresql-9.1

How could I achieve this in PostgreSQL??

I want to have a table with a timestamp field that automatically gets the value of now() on insert. The timestamp will never be updated. I assume I need to create a trigger to do this. If there is an easier way, please advise.

Perhaps, make the column so it has a default value of now, land then insert without specifying the timestamp column so it gets the default value?

create table foo (q_i_time timestamp with time zone not null default now(), someval int);

```
CREATE TABLE
billing=# insert into foo (someval) values (22);
INSERT 0 1
billing=# insert into foo (someval) values (26);
INSERT 0 1
billing=# insert into foo (someval) values (1);
INSERT 0 1
billing=# select * from foo;

           q_i_time            | someval
-------------------------------+---------
 2008-02-25 17:23:03.247619-08 |      22
 2008-02-25 17:23:07.43922-08  |      26
 2008-02-25 17:23:10.111189-08 |       1
(3 rows)
```

Can this autofilled timestamp column be the primary key?

Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a trigger, since you're not updating the timestamp. Simply declare a `DEFAULT`, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
    id integer primary key,
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp
);
```

example:

```
test=>     CREATE TABLE demo (
test(>         id integer primary key,
test(>         created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp
test(>     );
CREATE TABLE
test=> INSERT INTO demo(id) VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT 0 2
test=> INSERT INTO demo(id) VALUES(3);
INSERT 0 1
test=> SELECT * FROM demo;
 id |         created_at         
----+----------------------------
  1 | 2015-06-13 12:30:55.169221
  2 | 2015-06-13 12:30:55.169221
  3 | 2015-06-13 12:30:57.395104
(3 rows)
```

Note that the first two timestamps are the same since it was a single transaction. If you don't want that, use `clock_timestamp` instead of `current_timestamp`.

Note that applications can still override the timestamp by specifying it explicitly:

```
test=> INSERT INTO demo(id, created_at) VALUES (4, '2014-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT 0 1
test=> SELECT * FROM demo WHERE id = 4;
 id |     created_at      
----+---------------------
  4 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

You only need a trigger if you wish to *force* the value, or if you want to also *update* it when the row is updated.

Comment: Hi Craig, pls could you tell me what is the difference between DEFAULT = current_timestamp, and DEFAULT = now() ????

Comment: @litu16 There is no functional difference, but current_timestamp is the sql standard spelling.

Comment: @litu16 As for the "primary key" part of the question ... it can be, but remember that clocks have limited resolution so you might get duplicates resulting in errors. You would also have to use clock_timestamp as the default. I don't recommend using a captured timestamp as the pk

Comment: Hi Craig I search online about the cases in which timestamp as pk could produce duplicate errors, your are right. THanks. Acording to that research, I think that my best bet is to create a pk that is a kinda serial mixed with other columns values, what do you suggest???

Comment: @litu16 I'd use a `serial`. This is a case where the *natural* key, the timestamp, is imperfect because of limitations in the technology. In particular, on Windows timestamp precision is only 1 millisecond at best (until PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows 8, which improves that), so clashes are likely. That's exactly when a surrogate key like a `serial` column becomes appropriate.

Comment: hey Im using PostgreSQL 9.4 on Windows 8.1, I thought it was the last version, Isn't it?? Should I try that new postgres release? I has heard that serial also has its limitations, I remember it was in its bit size.

Comment: @litu16 9.5 isn't out yet, it's the version in late development. Serial will almost certainly be fine for you. There is bigserial too but if you do the maths you will figure out that by the time you exhaust the space in a serial you will have petabytes of data.

Comment: How to get it as a UNIX time stamp?